# MYSQL sub query inner join order by count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. One for `movies` (which lists `id,movie_title,movie_director` etc) and other is `likes` table: Which keeps track of how many people have added any particular movie to their favorites. It has only two fields `movie_id, user_id`. Both are `foreign key references` from corresponding tables (`movies` and `users`).

**Now I want to display all the movies sorted by most of number of likes.**

So I have to use select query and inside it I have to order it by sub query which counts number of likes for each movie.

Something like this?

```
select * 
from movies 
inner join likes 
on movies.id=likes.movie_id 
order by (
    select count * 
    from likes 
    where movie_id=?
)
```

I am really stuck here. Likes table has structure like this

```
user_id 1,movie_id 2, user_id 2, movie_id 2
```

So when selecting I should get movie with id 2 before others because it has 2 likes.

But how to do it?

Ahmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the subquery method that you started.  The key is to remove the outer join and just use a correlated subquery:

```
select * 
from movies
order by (select count(*)
          from likes 
          where movies.id = likes.movie_id 
         ) desc;
```

Comment: That' exactly how I wanted it :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to count the likes and sort by the count:

```
select m.id,
       m.movie_title,
       m.movie_director,
       count(l.movie_id) as num_likes
  from movies m
  left join likes l
    on m.id = l.movie_id
 group by m.id, m.movie_title, m.movie_director
 order by num_likes desc
```

This would do so in descending order (most likes first)

Comment: You may want to use a LEFT JOIN not to lose all movies that don't have likes.

Comment: `count(ifnull(l.movie_id,0))` will return 1 when `l.movie_id` is null. `count(l.movie_id)` should be enough

Comment: @FuzzyTree I confused it w/ a sum, was intending to just replace the count w/ a zero when there are none. I just moved the ifnull to the outside

Comment: Assuming m.id is unique you don't need the rest of the columns listed in the group by (mysql explicitly allows this behavior). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @DanielWilliams just because it allows what is essentially a syntax error to run doesn't mean that you should write it that way. In any other database it would return an error.

Comment: I don't think `count()` ever returns null. It seems that wrapping it in `ifnull` isn't necessary

Comment: @FuzzyTree did not realize

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a bit complicated as per my sql knowledge but greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia it is not a syntax error. It is valid mysql. Just because it is considered a syntax error in other DBs doesn't mean you should cater to other DBs. Not only is it not a syntax error it can be a huge performance improvement which is why mysql added this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a group by statement.

```
select m.id, count(*) as POPULARITY 
from movies m inner join likes l on m.id = l.movie_id 
group by m.id
order POPULARITY desc;
```

Per the above comment, this will exclude movies that have no likes. But better to start simple.